# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float' while looping and adding

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

while running the below code  I am getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
As per my requirement , I have a list of floating points numbers as string from an API , I want to convert them to float and find the avg

```
a= None
l=['2.35','4.25','9.9']
for num in l:
  a=a+float(num)
avg=a/len(l)
```

Comment: Why is `a` equal to None and not 0? That is what is causing your problem: `a+float(num)` You cannot do None + something

Comment: I find the error message pretty explicit. Is there a part of it that is unclear?

Comment: Alternative solution: `avg = sum(float(v) for v in l) / len(l)` or the more functional `avg = sum(map(float, l)) / len(l)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initiate your variable `a` to `0` instead of `None`. This will give you :

```py
a = 0
l=['2.35','4.25','9.9']
for num in l:
  a=a+float(num)
avg=a/len(l)
```

The error you have tells you that you cannot sum a `None` object with a float, which is exactly what you are trying to do at your first iteration of for loop.

When you initiate your variable `a` to `0`, you instead perform an addition of two numerical values, which is accepted by Python.